# Agrupar registros según fecha

Tags: mysql

días, noches espero que me puedan ayudar con poco con lo siguiente, la idea es lograr agrupar los registros usando mysql promediando y tenerlo por rangos de 1 minuto, 5 minutos, 15 minutos, 30 minutos, 60 minuts etc.

Actualmente estoy trabajando con un proyecto de arduino e iot donde es un jardín inteligente este envía un registro sobre sus sensores cada 10 segundos a la base de datos todo el tiempo, tengo una plataforma escrita en laravel para poder leer esos datos y representarlos en gráficas basados en el promedio estoy intentando lo siguiente

un ejemplo de mi tabla sensor_data

id, sensor_id, value, created_at

1, 1, 20, 2020-05-05 16:00:23

2, 1, 23, 2020-05-05 16:00:33

3, 1, 25, 2020-05-05 16:00:43

4, 1, 23, 2020-05-05 16:00:53

5, 1, 20, 2020-05-05 16:01:03

y mi consulta para obtenter el promedio en intervalos de 1 minuto es la siguiente

```
SELECT sensor_id, ROUND(AVG(value)) as average, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i')) as created FROM sensor_data WHERE value > 0 AND value < 1024 AND sensor_id=1 GROUP BY created ORDER BY created DESC
```

Y con esto obtengo el promedio de cada minuto, pero la duda aqui es que otra forma exise o me recomiendan para poder tener intervalos de 5, 15 o 30 minutos? ya que no puedo agruparlos con el created debido a que uso la fecha para separarlos.

Espero haberme explicado.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo algo así:

```
SELECT sensor_id, ROUND(AVG(value)) as average,
  CONCAT(
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y/%m/%d %H:'),
    ROUND(MINUTE(created_at)/15)*15
  ) as created 
  FROM sensor_data 
  WHERE value > 0 AND value < 1024 AND sensor_id=1 
  GROUP BY created ORDER BY created DESC;
```

De 00 a 15 te lo agrupa en 00, de 15 a 30 en 15 y así sucesivamente

Para 1, 5, 30 y 60, sustituye el 15 por estas cantidades

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo para redondear a intervalos de 5 minutos, para otros minutos cambia el valor de `@minuto`:

```sql
SET @created_at:= '2023-09-15 00:55:01';
SET @minuto := 5;

SELECT  CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@created_at,1,14),LPAD((MINUTE(@created_at) DIV @minuto)*@minuto,2,'0'),':00')
```